# How to install opencv and eclipse on a raspberry pi

Tags: software-installation, java, opencv

Is this possible? I've tried through command line but haven't found a clear tutorial yet. Would it be easier to accomplish this from gui or should I stick with the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the terminal to install OpenCV, [here](http://thinkrpi.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/step-3-install-softwares-for-webcam-and-computer-vision/) is a link with information on how to install OpenCV on your RaspberryPi.

And here is how to install eclipse:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think installing eclipse on Raspberry Pi is a good option as it is too heavy for it. I recommend [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)

Comment: Eclipse won't run on something with less than 1GB of ram (probably 4GB RAM minimum)

Comment: Sublime Text cannot be installed on Raspberry Pi. There is no version available for ARM.